# how to use mongoexport to get a particular format in .csv file?

Tags: macos, mongodb

I am new to mongoDb and exciting about using it at my workplace. However, I have come across a situation where one of our client has sent the data in .bson file. I have got everything working on machine. I want to use mongoexport facility to export my data in csv format. When I am using the following query

```
./mongoexport --db <dbname> -collection <collectionname> --csv -fields _id,field1,field2
```

I am getting the result in following format

```
ObjectID(4f6b42eb5e724242f60002ce),"[ { ""$oid"" : ""4f6b31295e72422cc5000001"" } ]",369008
```

However, I just want the value of the fields as a comma separated output like below: `4f6b42eb5e724242f60002ce,4f6b31295e72422cc5000001,369008`

My question is, is there anything that I can do something in mongoexport to ignore certain characters?

any pointer will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

No, mongoexport has no features like this. You'll need to use tools like sed and awk to post-process the file, or read the file and munge it in a scripting language like Python.

Comment: Thanks Jesse. Will try sed and awk. As of now I am trying Python.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add the following to your list of arguments:

--csv

You may also want to supply a path:

-o something.csv

...Though I don't think you could do this in 2012 when you first posted your question :-)